# How to resolve a variable in Kotlin, based on IOS solution?

Tags: android, ios, swift, variables, kotlin

Been trying to duplicate an iOS (Swift) solution in Android (Kotlin).  It's fairly straight forward, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, or if I need to change up my Kotlin code entirely. (Note this solution is working in Swift)

Here is what's going on in Swift:

```
enum CarID: String, Codable {

case carHeader
case carView
case dataView

var viewControllerType: UIViewController.Type {
    switch self {
    case .carView: return CarViewController.self
    case .carHeader: return CarHeaderViewController.self
    case .dataView: return DataViewController.self
    }
}
```

}

Now my attempt to match it in Kotlin:

```
enum class ModuleID(val type: String) {

CAR_HEADER("carHeader"),
CAR_VIEW("carView"),
DATA_VIEW("dataView");

val activityType: AppCompatActivity  // Wrong return type?
    get() = when(this) {
        CAR_HEADER -> **CarHeader**  // Error here 
        CAR_VIEW -> CarView
        DATA_VIEW -> DataView
    }
```

}

Note I am simply trying to use ActivityViewTypes, just as iOS is using the viewControllerType.  The behavior should be near exact.

The error I am seeing reads: "Classifier 'CarHeader' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here."

I attempted to create said companion object, but it just didn't seem necessary, so I backed off.  Any suggestions are welcomed!  I've also considered looking into a Sealed Class, but not sure if that is necessary here, either.

I have also not addressed the 'Codable - if someone wants to delve into that, that is fine as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `Type`, and not an instance, so you'd probably want to return a class, so in Java terms:

```
UIViewController.Type ==> `Class<? extends Activity>`
```

With that in mind, following should work:

```
val activityType: Class<out Activity>
    get() = when(this) {
        CAR_HEADER -> CarHeader::class.java
        CAR_VIEW -> CarView::class.java
        DATA_VIEW -> DataView::class.java
    } 
}
```

Which you can even use like

```
startActivity(Intent(this, module.activityType))
```

Comment: Excellent!  This worked great - and it was the 'out Activity' you suggested in the comment.  Great catch, it would have stumped me. 

I appreciate it! 

(Up voted you, but it doesn't show yet since I haven't posted much on here)

Comment: If it worked then you'll need to tick that checkmark on the left to indicate that this is the accepted answer because it is the solution to the problem (something something), I've edited the answer to say "out" thanks :D